# SQL Server- Table rows to data dictionary conversion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have two tables, Table1 and Table2 as below.

Table1

```
ID  Col1  Col2  Col3
--  ----  ----  ----
 1     X     Y     Z
```

Table2

```
ID  Col1  Col2  Col3
--  ----  ----  ----
 1     1     2     3
```

I want to write a stored procedure, to return result something like below. And have to achieve this result without using cursor.

Result

```
Key  Value  
---  -----
  X      1
  Y      2  
  Z      3
```

```
Edited:

I required one result set.

Both IDs are parameter of my Store Procedure.
```

Comment: You want to return 2 result sets?

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: You'll have to explain *why* you get the result before anyone can help. Are the ID's what makes them key-value pairs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server 2008, you can use CROSS APPLY with VALUES to unpivot data.  You can first JOIN the two table on the id column and then unpivot it into the `key`/`value` columns:

```
select [key], value
from
(
  select t1.col1, t2.col1 t2_col1, 
    t1.col2, t2.col2 t2_col2, 
    t1.col3, t2.col3 t2_col3
  from table1 t1
  inner join table2 t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
) src
cross apply
(
  values
  (col1, t2_col1),
  (col2, t2_col2),
  (col3, t2_col3)
) c ([key], value);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/15800)

Answer (score 1):

```
select  t1.col1 as [Key]
,       t2.col1 as Value
from    dbo.Table1 t1
join    dbo.Table2 t2
on      t1.id = t2.id
union all
select  t1.col2
,       t2.col2
from    dbo.Table1 t1
join    dbo.Table2 t2
on      t1.id = t2.id
union all
select  t1.col3
,       t2.col3
from    dbo.Table1 t1
join    dbo.Table2 t2
on      t1.id = t2.id
```